# Teams Tab for dynamic SharePoint page / authentication problem

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Heyo,

I am trying to build a multi tenant Teams App with personal tabs. The goal is: the user is authenticated (silently like explained [in the Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad), a static html page with the JavaScript code is hosted in an Azure Storage), then my custom web service is called and answers with a SharePoint-Online URL which contains an SPFX Webpart. Then the user is redirected to that page. When the user is not registered he gets an error page instead. The problem here is, that I am not able to redirect the user to that SharePoint page. The SharePoint page won't open in the iframe of the Teams tab because the tab's domain is the domain where my static web page is hosted. So my first question is how can I achieve this? (I do not know the SharePoint URL at build time, i do not know if the user has a page at all. This is determined in the custom web service at runtime)

A different approach would be to build a custom JavaScript application (in react, like my SPFX webpart), host it on my static web page and communicate with the SharePoint from there. To test my idea I added permissions for SharePoint in my Azure AD application, wrote a simple call to the SharePoint with the obtained token.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitecollection]/_api/web/lists", false);
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
          var result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      }
};
req.send();
```

The problem is my SharePoint is answering with 401 and "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown" error in the response.

Is this some sort of CORS problem or do I need a different type of token for SharePoint? Or do I have to use a complete different JavaScript library to authenticate vs SharePoint.

Comment: Are you sending following parameters [Client_ID, Client_Secret and Resource] in your request body?

Comment: No I am just using the token I got. I have no secret, since I do not want to handle the exchange in JavaScript. I want a silent login like it is possible with graph for example with an azure ad application. I mean - in azure ad I can choose SharePoint and set permissions...whats the point of giving permissions in the app for SharePoint if one is not able to use them with the token?